# A problem on elementary Number theory #1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a positive integer with all digits equal to 5 such that $2003 \mid N$. Find $\frac{N}{2003} \mod 10^6$.

Well, I am not getting the problem correctly which is why I hesitate to show my workings for the problem.

Comment: Do not hesitate, show us what you did.

Comment: Show them anyway. We're here to help. You'll benefit more.

Comment: Please use MathJax.

Comment: @Shaun: The question seems to be perfectly understandable as it is.

Comment: Hint:  $2003$ is invertible $\pmod {10^6}$.  Find the inverse.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then $2003^{-1}\equiv 888667\bmod 1000000$.

Comment: Thanks for the cooperation! Yes, Only number I found is N=5555..5(2003 times) which is divisible by 2003. My idea was to denote the sum of n digits in the number N as S(n). A little computation gave me Some(402)=5*402=2050 which isn't divisible by 2003. So I tried multiples of 2003 and found S(2003)=5.2003=10,015 which is divisible by 2003.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Start with $0$ and iterate the operation $n\mapsto 10n+5$ modulo $2003$. Since $10$ is invertible, this operation permutes the numbers between $0$ and $2002$, and therefore your starting number _must_ be in a cycle.

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury: Pretty sure there should be only 2002 fives. By Fermat's little theorem, for any prime $p>5$, a repdigit with $p-1$ digits is a multiple of $p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Well, $\frac N{2003}\equiv N\times 2003^{-1}$ so you have to multiply your value by $555555$.

Comment: @lulu How to know that a number is invertible modulo some number?

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury: $a$ is invertible modulo $n$ exactly if $a$ and $n$ are coprime. (See [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)).

Comment: Thanks @HenningMakholm ! I have a clearer picture now

Comment: @AnuranChowdhury: In your comment above you seem to assume that a long number is divisible by 2003 if its sum of digits is. This is most definitely not true (it works for divisibility by 3 and 9, but not any other numbers).

Comment: Hi @HenningMakholm That looks like it but actually I found that using the notation S(n) for sum of n digits helped me find the N quickly. But that's just me and it's a rough work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $2003$ is coprime to $10^6$, so there is exactly one solution to $ 2003 x \equiv 555555 \pmod{10^6}$.

Comment: I was on the same lines but to find x, I apply Euler's theorem (Phi function) and it becomes tedious. Any other way to do ?

Comment: Sure, try using the extended Euclidean algorithm to find the inverse of 2003 mod $10^6$

Edit: it will be a bit tedious just because $10^6$ is fairly big, but it's not too tricky

Comment: @Anuran The answer is $\,x\equiv -555\cdot 444333.\ $ **Challenge:** explain why it has that form

Comment: 2003*111333 == 1 (mod 10^6)

Hence, x = 111333*555555 mod 10^6 . Right?